# function optional properties in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have one function by 2 optional property 
and how send value hight?

```
function test($size=1,$hight=2){
// code .........
}
```

```
 test($hight)
 test(null,$hight);
```

Is there any other way?
I dont need test(null,$hight);

Comment: change the order?

Comment: test function use an other file and I cant change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like it, May be it will help to you.

```
function test($hight=null,$size=null){
 // code .........
}
$hight = 2;
$size = 1;
test($hight)
test($hight,''); // if you pass as '' - blank even it's work and if second parameter is not given even it will work.
```

Comment: I use this way
And I think this is better 
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the function to something like this?

```php
function test() {
      $args = func_get_args();

      /** now you can access these as $args[0], $args[1] **/
 }
```

Comment: thank you ,
I need a way to send data and I cant change function 
because this function use another files